# Is there a way to check if the current application is a misx application

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, packaging, msix

I am converting a C#/WPF application that is currently deployed with ClickOnce to MSIX. I would like to check in code, if the current execution is from within an MSIX package or if just the .exe is executed, similar to the `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetWorkDeployed` Property of ClickOnce.
As a workaround at the moment I use a try catch block trying to access Package.Current.Displayname and set an isMsix Property in the catch block, but I wondered if there is a better way using some methode or property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detect package identity and runtime context

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/detect-package-identity

Use `IsRunningAsUwp()` from the `DesktopBridge.Helpers`.

https://github.com/qmatteoq/DesktopBridgeHelpers/

https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/sparse-package/